# Radio button arranging problem

Tags: android

How can we put a number of radio button in multiple rows and columns within single radio group.

(For example: If there are 10 radio buttons in single radio group. 5 should be in first row and the next 5 in second row because of device width is small.)

Comment: Use relative layout for radio group then you can manage it easily .by giving relative position to all radio button .try it dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scroll view with horizontal scroll in each roll i have given hierarchal to you apply this hierarchal layout than you find solution of your question.

```
Table roow(your table row)
   -Put Relative layout 
       -Put scroll view (horizontally)
           -put Radio Group
              -put RadioBitton1,RadioBitton2,RadioBitton3,RadioBitton4, RadioBitton5
            -Put scroll view (horizontally)
                -put RadioBitton1,RadioBitton2,RadioBitton3,RadioBitton4, RadioBitton5
             -Close Radio Group
             -close all

than you find your radio button scroll horizontally scroll row wise.
```

I hope this is help.