# Android RadioButtons

Tags: android, radio-button

How can I display four radio buttons which are inside a radioGroup on android such that the positions of the radio buttons are as follow:

top left
top right
bottom left
bottom right

Comment: you can't, radiogroup is a linear layout

Comment: Possible to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946086/radio-button-arranging-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this link [Images of Radio Button](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) -> Download images of Radio button (both presses and unpressed) -> set unpressed Radio button image as background image of **button** widget and onclick change image of button to pressed Radio button image.

You can use Relative layout the to position the button and other properties of Radio button you have define in your own logic in Java code for simple buttons.